# Cannot connect remotely to Kafka docker container

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am running Kafka using a Docker Compose file:

```
version: "2"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181

  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://172.16.1.109:9092
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1"
```

However, when I try and produce a message using my C# client, using "bootstrap.servers: 172.16.1.109:9092" it times out.

Is there another setting that I need?

Comment: Is the IP address correct?

Comment: This is docker-compose.yml file example from _wurstmeister/kafka_ image maintainer  https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml. Just use your IP address to advertise.

Is this your local environment?